# bar code scanner implementation in android

Tags: android

I have a problem that I have to create my self bar code scanner of my app not using any precode as zxing as barcode scanner app of google. I want my self code of bar code scanner in my app because my client doen't want any dependency on any other app. So, what will I do? becoz I have searched this on web but nothing get right result. PLease help me.

Answer (score 0):

Programming a barcode scanner application yourself is a **very difficult** task and most likely when you tell your client the amount of money it will cost, they will change their mind about dependencies and third party libraries.

However, since [ZXing](http://code.google.com/p/zxing/) is an open source project, you can import that library into your project and have it 'built-in' and included into your project (without the need for the user to download an additional application).  You will still be using their code, so you'll have to abide by their [license](http://www.apache.org/licenses/LICENSE-2.0), but your users will no longer have to have 'Barcode Scanner' installed to use your application.